# Xubuntu 12.04 - the newest nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I use Xubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have added the `xorg-edgers` repo for apt:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
```

It contains nvidia-346 drivers but the newest driver is nvidia-352. Is it possible to install nvidia-352 on Xubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this](https://launchpad.net/~mamarley/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia), or install directly from the Nvidia [drivers page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).